# Is it possible to vectorize, applying compare_ssim to every combination of images in two sets in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, ssim

I have two sets of images stored as 3D numpy arrays.  All the images are the same size (28X28).  I'd like to compare the images in each set to each other using compare_ssim.  I have written the below code which is very slow.  I've tried to vectorize using numpy.apply_along_axis but this fails with a X.shape<>Y.shape error.  Any suggestions?

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim

def max_ssim(image,ref_images):
    max_score = -1 #Minimum SSIM score possible is -1
    for ref_image in ref_images:
        score = ssim(image,ref_image)
        if score > max_score:
            max_score = score
    return max_score

def overlap_between_sets(test_set, ref_set):
    #return a vector for each row of the test set which 
    #contains the MAX SSIM Score found against ref_set
    # SSIM scores range between -1 and 1 where 1 is identical.

    overlap = np.ndarray(test_set.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)
    for i, obs in enumerate(test_set):
        overlap[i] = max_mse_vec(obs,ref_set)
    return overlap

test_to_train_overlap = overlap_between_sets(test_dataset,train_dataset)
```

Comment: The formula for SSIM is not that complex, just a function of the sliding window means and variances, plus the covariance between two images. You could code it up yourself using scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter, http://stackoverflow.com/a/37836209/483620

Comment: If you did ever get this coded up, I would love to see the code.